# Timer Does Not Start

Tags: java

Timer does not start, is the null return type wrong.
Or the return type must be new timertask.

```
package testing;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class myClass {
    public static TimerTask run() {
        System.out.println("hello.");
        return null;
    }
    public static void setTimer(int seconds) {
        Timer timerObject = new Timer();
        timerObject.scheduleAtFixedRate(run(), 0, 1000);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        setTimer(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to execute a timer task you probably need to actually create a timer task.

Comment: return null will do that for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You are currently expecting `run()` to be the `TimerTask` , but `run` is supposed to return an instance of `TimerTask`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign TimerTask object to scheduleAtFixedRate function, your run function is returning null, not TimerTask object.

```
package testing;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class myClass {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello.");
        }
    };
    public static void setTimer(int seconds) {
        Timer timerObject = new Timer();
        timerObject.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        setTimer(1);
    }
}
```